# How to Make React Navbar change background color on scroll to work properly?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, styled-components

Here is my codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-sunset-smk2f?file=/src/Navbar.js

So, my navbar on page refresh currently shows red, but it should be transparent. Also, when you scroll it turns transparent for the first 100px, then switches back to red again. Any reason how to fix this?

It should be transparent by default, then change to red, but it's not working properly.

```
        const changeBackground = () => {
          if (window.pageYOffset >= 100 && location.pathname === "/") {
            setNavbar(window.pageYOffset);
          } else {
            setNavbar(false);
          }
        };

        useEffect(() => {
          const watchScroll = () => {
            window.addEventListener("scroll", changeBackground);
          };
          watchScroll();
          // Remove listener (like componentWillUnmount)
          return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("scroll", changeBackground);
          };
        }, []);
```

I only want it to be transparent on my home page `"/"` then turn red after I scroll 100px. But for the about page I just want it to permanently be red and disable the scroll function.

Update: So I figured out if I remove this code, then the scroll works normally if I scroll past 100px value, but the issue is now I can't update the navbar color based on location pathname?

```
  useEffect(() => {
if (location.pathname) {
  setNavbar(location.pathname);
}

console.log(location.pathname);
}, [location.pathname]);
```

This was my function to find the location of the page I was on, but it kept causing issues with my scroll function. So how can I check for the page route without ruining my scroll function?

Answer (score 0):

I have created the codesandbox, which I guess works as you expected, it only need some modification in useEfeect function.
https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-chandrasekhar-skr7i?file=/src/Navbar.js

Comment: so I ended up solved my issue by deleting the useEffect for location and just creating a change background function then passing it into my styles. Do you see any issues with the method I did? I added it to my question above